# JSP import class causing error

Tags: jsp, ubuntu, tomcat8, geany

This is my first attempt for JSP. I am using TOMCAT8 and Geany to write on. I placed the application folder in `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/Jproject` and classes in `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/Jproject/WEB-INF/classes`.

my class file `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/Jproject/WEB-INF/classes/test.class` is;

```
public class test
{
public static void PP()
{
System.out.println("yoyo");
}
}
```

and my index.jsp `(/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/Jproject/index.jsp)` is;

```
<%@ page import="Jproject.test.*" %> 
<DOCTYPE! html> 
<html> 
<head>
<title>Project</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<%  String x = "java";
    out.println("Hello " + x + "Worlds");   
test.PP(); %> 
</body> 
</html>
```

when i run it on a browser `http://localhost:8080/Jproject/` i get the following error;

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 12 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
test cannot be resolved
9:  String x = "java";
10: 
11:     out.println("Hello " + x + "Worlds");
12:     test.PP();
13: %>
14: </body>
15: </html>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:449)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:401)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:345)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 (Ubuntu) logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 (Ubuntu)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you must create classes under src folder not a `WEB-INF` folder and jsp file create under `webapp` folder.

Comment: i'm not using eclipse. i'm trying to write it on Geany. is there a xml file i have to create?